# How to do Map Navigation for iPhone support?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Here is Google Map Navigation for Android Mobiles:
  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwggXqMZZ8w

Can we achieve this functionality for iphone? Is there any map api available for this which provides directions and details on GPS bases as well text (source to destination) bases?

If Yes, please provide some links regarding those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is against google's terms of service (relating to MapKit) to do turn by turn navigation, however you can work around it using the google maps web api and create custom code.

Comment: Is there any other way for that? Is there any other MAP API provider available which provides workflow? How to create my own application which same scope/flow like some iphone applications such as, iGo My way, AT&T Navigator, TomTom U.S. & Canada, etc. are having?

Comment: I know TomTom has all sorts of special deals with Apple, so I would assume that if they use google maps they would also have a special arrangement and the same goes for AT&T. I believe that TomTom has its own satellites for navigation as well. To implement your own I have heard that the web api for google maps is the way to go

Comment: This article is dated but it says Core Location can be used http://www.pocketgpsworld.com/iPhone-OS-3.0---Turn-By-Turn-Nav-Gets-The-Green-Light-9367.php

Comment: http://cloudmade.com/products/navi-studio This looks like the API you are looking for. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**For speech recognition you can use this:**

I used 
[Open Ears](http://www.politepix.com/openears), which was quite easy and works really fine for text-to-speech and recognition.

> OpenEars is an open source framework for performing continuous speech
>   recognition, text-to-speech, and language model generation in iOS. It
>   uses the CMU Pocketsphinx, CMU Flite and MITLM libraries.

Comment: Thanks Malte O. for replying.

Have you any idea about any apis which provides custom maps and directions with voice functionality?

Comment: I don't know if there is an api with integrated voice functionality. But i can suggest Route Me: http://code.google.com/p/route-me/ which provides functionalities like tracking and many more. Directions you can get over GPS then.

Comment: route-me does not provide direction based services. I guess in route-me they have just created diff diff css files which get combined to google map while loading. That's why in that application only look gets changed other things are as it is. What I require to build is some applications like iGo My way, AT&T Navigator, TomTom U.S. & Canada, etc ?